# Copy and Rename Multiple Files with Regular Expressions in bash

Tags: regex, bash, copy, rename

I've got a file structure that looks like:

```
A/
    2098765.1ext
    2098765.2ext
    2098765.3ext
    2098765.4ext
      12345.1ext
      12345.2ext
      12345.3ext
      12345.4ext

B/
    2056789.1ext
    2056789.2ext
    2056789.3ext
    2056789.4ext
      54321.1ext
      54321.2ext
      54321.3ext
      54321.4ext
```

I need to rename all the files that begin with `20` to start with `10`; i.e., I need to rename `B/2022222.1ext` to `B/1022222.1ext`

I've seen many of the other questions regarding renaming multiple files, but couldn't seem to make it work for my case. Just to see if I can figure out what I'm doing before I actually try to do the copy/renaming I've done:

```
for file in "*/20?????.*"; do
    echo "{$file/20/10}";
done
```

but all I get is

```
{*/20?????.*/20/10}
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: file globs are not regular expressions.

Comment: Well, I'd like to use regular expressions, because I can't figure out how to make it work with globs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just have a little bit of incorrect syntax is all:

```
for file in */20?????.*; do mv $file ${file/20/10}; done
```

1. Remove quotes from the argument to `in`.  Otherwise, the filename expansion does not occur.
2. The `$` in the substitution should go *before* the bracket

Comment: Love the simple way to do this.

Comment: do you know of a page explaining the type of regex/wildcard rules that apply in `${file/20/10}`? seems regex and bash wildcards are sometimes in conflict

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution which use the `find` command:

```
find . -name '20*' | while read oldname; do echo mv "$oldname" "${oldname/20/10}"; done
```

This command does not actually do your bidding, it only prints out what should be done. Review the output and if you are happy, remove the `echo` command and run it for real.

Comment: Wish I could have accepted two answers. I chose the other one because it was simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanna add to Explosion Pill's answer.
On OS X though, you must say

```
mv "${file}" "${file_expression}"
```

Or the `mv` command does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansions like :

```
{*/20?????.*/20/10}
```

can't be surrounded by quotes.

Instead, try doing (with Perl `rename`) :

```
rename 's/^10/^20/' */*.ext
```

You can do this using the Perl tool [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) from the `shell` prompt. (There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.)

If you want to do a dry run to make sure you don't clobber any files, add the `-n` switch to the command.

### note

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

This seems to be the default `rename` command on `Ubuntu`.

To make it the default on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `rename` do a dry run so I know what it's doing before I do it? I don't want to mess up what I've already got.

Answer (score -1):

The glob behavior of `*` is suppressed in double quotes.  Try:

```
for file in */20?????.*; do
    echo "${file/20/10}";
done
```

Comment: This just appended "/20/10" to each of the filenames.